# Is there a way to visualize the feasible region for a set of linear inequalities in plotly in 2d? in 3d?

Tags: python, graph, plotly, linear-programming

Is there a way to visualize the feasible region for a set of linear inequalities in plotly in 2d? in 3d?

Say I have the inequalities:

[image]

How can I visualize the feasible region in Plotly? What about if my region is in 3d? I know that we can do this in other libraries (e.g. matplotlib), but I specifically want to do this in plotly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think so.

A few months ago I stumbled on the same problem as I was developing a new plotting module for SymPy. After testing different things, these are my conclusions:

- Matplotlib offers at least two ways to achieve that: either with `ax.contour` (and setting the contour levels) or with `ax.fill`.
- Plotly's `go.Contour` doesn't currently support setting contour levels (see [issue 4503](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/4503)). This results in difficult to read plots. Here is a comparison of the first inequality that you posted with Matplotlib (blue region is where the inequality is true) and Plotly (yellow region is where the inequality is true).

[image]
[image]

- Plotly doesn't implement a feature similar to `ax.fill`.
- Plotly exposes the `go.Heatmap`, but it is not suitable for this application.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer! Do you know if there's a way to figure out the bounds of the feasible region using matplotlib, then visualize the result in plotly?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. I tried several bounds until I found the one I was happy with.